# Python- Calculate Average Number Using Two Lists

Tags: python, list, integer

I'm trying to calculate the average length of sentences in a .txt file by dividing the number of words by number of full stops:-

```
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

file = open("File One.txt", "r")
data = file.read()

words = data.split()
print('Number of words in text file:', len(words))

count = data.count('.')
print("Number of full stops:", count)

num1 = words
num2 = count

print("Average sentence length:", divide(num1, num2))
```

But I end up with:-

```
Number of words in text file: 25
Number of full stops: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Data\stripped down.py", line 16, in <module>
    print("Average sentence length:", divide(num1, num2))
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Data\stripped down.py", line 2, in divide
    return x / y
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `num1` is defined to be the word list itself rather than its length. This question is basically a typo. Also , what is the point of `divide`? Defining a function rather than just using the operator is more typing which just makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 0):

you are directly passing list `num1`  as it is, but you need assign its length to `num1`

```
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y


file = open("File One.txt", "r")
data = file.read()

words = data.split()
print('Number of words in text file:', len(words))

count = data.count('.')
print("Number of full stops:", count)

num1 = len(words)
num2 = count

print("Average sentence length:", divide(num1, num2))
```

sample Output:

```
Number of words in text file: 9
Number of full stops: 12
Average sentence length: 0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

`print("Average sentence length:", divide(num1, num2))` calls `def divide(x, y)`. num1 is a list, as can be seen here:

```
data = file.read()
words = data.split()
```

For example if your string was `data = "abc def ghi jkl"`, `data.split()` will return a list (`['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']`).

In your specific example, you could use `len()` to access the length of said list - you will therefore have an int, which in the end is dividable, so:

```
#[...]
num1 = len(words)
num2 = count

print("Average sentence length:", divide(num1, num2))
```